# I keep getting the "Method does not override any method from its superclass" in Xcode 7. How do I fix it?

Tags: xcode, swift

I am trying to create a drag and drop object so I put in this code.  Create a image and create a action and the name being Person.

```
var location = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
```

the action goes here

```
override func touchesBegan(touches:NSSet!, withEvent event: UIEvent!) {

    var touch : UITouch! = touches.anyObject() as! UITouch

    location = touch.locationInView(self.view)

    Person.center = location
}
override func touchesMoved(touches:NSSet!, withEvent event: UIEvent!) {

    var touch : UITouch! = touches.anyObject() as! UITouch

    location = touch.locationInView(self.view)

    Person.center = location
}
```

Comment: remove `override`. The error says: Method (-> func) does not override. You are using the `override` keyword. Listen to Xcode ;)

Comment: You are probably using an outdated tutorial. `touches:NSSet!` has long be replaced by `touches: Set<...>` (but the exact signature changes with each new Swift release :)

Comment: I tryed removing override.